# Image metadata (EXIF) with c#

Tags: c#, metadata, bitmapimage

I am using the following code and the code is working for some images is fine but most images EXIF data is not getting.

```
ImageMetadata imageMetadata = new ImageMetadata();
public ImageMetadata ReadEXIFMetadata(string filepath)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    System.Drawing.Image image__1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs);
    PropertyItem[] imagePropertyItems = image__1.PropertyItems;

    foreach (PropertyItem pi in imagePropertyItems)
    {
        switch ((EXIFProperty)pi.Id)
        {
           case EXIFProperty.Title:
                imageMetadata.Title = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(pi.Value);
                break;
           case EXIFProperty.Author:
                imageMetadata.Author = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(pi.Value);
                //imageMetadata.Author = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(pi.Value)
                break;
           case EXIFProperty.Keywords:
                imageMetadata.Keywords = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(pi.Value);
                break;
           case EXIFProperty.Comments:
                imageMetadata.Comments = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(pi.Value);
                //imageMetadata.Comments = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(pi.Value)
                break;
           default:
                break;
        }
    }
    fs.Close();    
    return imageMetadata;
}


public enum EXIFProperty
{
    Title = 40091,
    Author = 40093,
    Keywords = 40094,
    Comments = 40092
}
public class ImageMetadata
{
    private string _title = string.Empty;
    private string _author = string.Empty;
    private string _keywords = string.Empty;
    private string _comments = string.Empty;
    public ImageMetadata()
    {
        this._title = string.Empty;
        this._author = string.Empty;
        this._keywords = string.Empty;
        this._comments = string.Empty;
    }
    public ImageMetadata(string title, string author, string keywords, string comments)
    {
        this._title = title;
        this._author = author;
        this._keywords = keywords;
        this._comments = comments;
    }
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return this._title;
        }
        set
        {
            this._title = value;
        }
    }
    public string Author
    {
        get
        {
            return this._author;
        }
        set
        {
            this._author = value;
        }
    }
    public string Keywords
    {
        get
        {
            return this._keywords;
        }
        set
        {
            this._keywords = value;
        }
    }
    public string Comments
    {
        get
        {
            return this._comments;
        }
        set
        {
            this._comments = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Correct me if I am doing something wrong in the above code.please help stuck with this problem.

Comment: `return imageMetadata` is returning empty there is no error getting

Comment: Have you checked that the image has EXIF properties? Have you placed breakpoints into your code to see where it is going in and what is/isn't being set?

Comment: @BerndLinde yes!! I had but there is no error getting.

Comment: Even without errors, is your code going into the `foreach` and one of the non-default switch statements?

Comment: Yes code is going to the `foreach` as well

Comment: @BerndLinde once you try the same code ...I think you will batter understand :)

Comment: _"but most images EXIF data is not getting"_ - confirm that the images actually have EXIF info.  Bring up file properties in Windows Explorer on the **Details** tab.  There you should see _Camera, Advanced Photo_ properties

Comment: @MickyDuncan Agree with you but the image which i have using ,have all the EXIF properties Like -Camera,Tags,author,Description as well.

Comment: You might need to provide an image with your example as your code works if using an image that has EXIF data

Comment: Okay!! i will update it

Comment: @BerndLinde Had update please check :)

Comment: The image you uploaded doesn't have Author, Title or any of the properties that you are extracting. Hence why your resulting values out of the method are empty

Comment: @BerndLinde No!! Title and tag is available

Comment: Take a look at the image you uploaded, it has non of the exif information in it. That is the sample we are getting, the code works, the image doesn't have the details you are looking for

Comment: Actually  The main purpose is to extract keywords and Title from the image.and both are added into Image @BerndLinde

Comment: You cannot extract information from an image if that image doesn't contain the data

Comment: Opps !! after upload all EXIF tags are deleted automatically :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you've created your own `ImageMetaData` class as .NET already has one. Try:

```
BitmapCreateOptions createOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat | BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreColorProfile;
BitmapMetadata importedMetaData = new BitmapMetadata("jpg");
using (Stream sourceStream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    BitmapDecoder sourceDecoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(sourceStream, createOptions, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
    // Check source is has valid frames 
    if (sourceDecoder.Frames[0] != null && sourceDecoder.Frames[0].Metadata != null)
    {
        sourceDecoder.Frames[0].Metadata.Freeze();
        // Get a clone copy of the metadata
        BitmapMetadata sourceMetadata = sourceDecoder.Frames[0].Metadata.Clone() as BitmapMetadata;
        importedMetaData = sourceMetadata;
    }
}
return importedMetaData;
```

Comment: But i am not finding any library for `BitmapCreateOptions ` in my pprject

Comment: @Gitz the using statement `using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;` above your namespace and make sure you are referencing `PresentationCore.dll` (which it automatically is if this is a WPF application)